# Emacs, right click to copy selection

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs 24, in a previous version (23 I think) I use to be able to do a single right click on a region to copy (**copy-region-as-kill**) it to clipboard.

But that functionality no longer works. It's similar to the double right click to cut (**yank**) which still works, but I cannot figure how to implement the single right click copy.

Thanks.

edit:

I found [this in the emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mouse-Commands.html) where the behaviour is described in the four bullet points at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I solved it with defadvice:

```
(defadvice mouse-save-then-kill (around mouse2-copy-region activate)
  (when (region-active-p)
    (copy-region-as-kill (region-beginning) (region-end)))
  ad-do-it)
```

I've had this problem for ages, so when I finally ask about it I figure it out right after...

Answer (score 1):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-3>") 'copy-region-as-kill)
```

Comment: It works, but it overwrites the the double right click cut behaviour, is there a way to have both?

Comment: I'm not sure, try `(global-set-key (kbd "<down-mouse-3> <mouse-3>") 'mouse-save-then-kill)`

Comment: A popup menu just appears now.

Comment: Aquamacs has a fully customizable right-click menu, if you are on OSX.  I've borrowed that functionality and am using it with both Emacs Trunk and Aquamacs interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation for mouse-save-then-kill:

> If `mouse-drag-copy-region` is non-nil, this command also saves the
>   new region to the kill ring (replacing the previous kill if the
>   previous region was just saved to the kill ring).

If you follow the link to the documentation for
mouse-drag-copy-region:

> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 24.1 of Emacs.

I believe the real source of the issue is that this default changed to
nil, so you should not need to use defadvice. If you do `M-x customize-variable` `mouse-drag-copy-region` and
set it to a non-nil value such as `t` it should restore the old
behavior.